# Reducing CSS in Webpack project

Tags: css, webpack, postcss-loader, purifycss

Looking for the best way to eliminate redundant CSS code in my Webpack project ie. I'm importing a local Bootstrap css file in the `src` folder, but use very little of it.

vendor.scss:

```
@import "./css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

vendor.js:

```
import './vendor.scss';
```

From googling, I've came across both `PurifyCSSPlugin` and a way to do it via `postcss-loader` - however, when I try to install these, they fail as I presume they're now depreciated.

All help and guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Purge CSS](https://purgecss.com/)?